# Ember: How to apply different stylesheets depending on the language?

Tags: css, ember.js, internationalization

I want to create an Ember application with two languages: one of them is `rtl` and the other is `ltr`.

How can I create two different stylesheets that one will loaded when I need `rtl` and one will loaded when I need `ltr`?

I'm using ember 2.8.

Comment: Minor style thing: end your sentences with a ".". [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) you can find other useful tips and tricks to tune your English quickly.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways.

The first one - keep styles for different directions in different files and use only one of them. There is an obvious negative thing - you have to double your rules.

The second way - to keep it in the single way, but separate by css classes.  Just add a language-related css class to the body, for example, `.en` or `.th`. Then modify your css for these classes:

```css
div {
  color: red;
}

.....

.th {
  div {
    color: blue;
    direction: rtl;
  }
}
```

If you select this way, I would encourage you to use a global `lang` attribute for the `body` tag instead of custom class names. It will make your css a little complex, but the semantic of your code will be perfect.